# create a filter expression (i) dynamically in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Having a data.table

```
library(data.table)
dd <- data.table(x=1:10,y=10:1,z=20:20)
```

I can filter it using

```
dd[x %in% c(1, 3) & z %in% c(12, 20)]
   x  y  z
1: 1 10 20
2: 3  8 20
```

Now I would like to create the same filter dynamically. This what I have tried so far:

```
cond <- list(x=c(1,3),z=c(12,20))
vars <- names(cond)
## dd[get(vars[[1]]) %in% cond[[1]] & get(vars[[2]]) %in% cond[[2]]]

EVAL = function(...){
  expr <- parse(text=paste0(...))
  print(expr)
  eval(expr)
  }

dd[ EVAL(vars, " %in% ", cond, collapse=" & ") ]
```

But I still get an error:

```
 Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : object 'x' not found
```

even if the expression evalutaed looks good:

```
expression(x %in% c(1, 3) & z %in% c(12, 20))
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You are probably looking for a general solution, but for your specific task, it seems to me that you could just do something like `EVAL = function(x, vars, cond){ setkeyv(x, vars) ; x[do.call(CJ, cond), nomatch = 0L] } ; EVAL(dd, vars, cond)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes I am looking for a general solution. But I like your solution. I think it is more efficient than my attempt to eavl/parse expressions.. can you please change your comment to an answer with some explanations?

Comment: `dd[rowSums(mapply(\`%in%\`, dd[names(cond)], cond)) == length(cond), ]` in base

Comment: The costly way is: take the Cartesian product of the elements of `cond` and then join the result: `dd[do.call(CJ,cond), on=names(cond), nomatch=0]` (Oh, I see David posted something similar above.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building expression instead of parsing it.

```
library(data.table)
dd = data.table(x=1:10,y=10:1,z=20:20)
AndIN = function(cond){
    Reduce(
        function(x, y) call("&", call("(",x), call("(",y)),
        lapply(names(cond), function(var) call("%in%", as.name(var), cond[[var]]))
    )
}
cond = list(x=c(1,3),z=c(12,20))
AndIN(cond)
#(x %in% c(1, 3)) & (z %in% c(12, 20))
dd[eval(AndIN(cond))]
#   x  y  z
#1: 1 10 20
#2: 3  8 20
```

Calls `call("(",x)` and `call("(",y)` may not be necessary.