# data.table: using colnames for assignment by reference

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use column names for an assignment by reference (:=) within a data.table. The function called is doing some calculation per row over several columns. I use the current development version of data.table (v1.9.7), which makes the parameter "with=TRUE" unnecessary.

A running minimal example with explicit variable names is:

```
DT <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = seq(2, 20, 2), c = seq(5, 50, 5))
DT[, out := sum(a, b), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

But if I have a lot of columns and I call the function with a single variable containing the (selected) column names, the code fails:

```
DT  <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = seq(2, 20, 2))
col <- colnames(DT)
DT[, out := sum(col), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

**EDIT:**

David Arenburg's answer `DT[, out := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = col]` works for this specific case. But I do not really understand how this approach can be applied to another function call. I wrote the following function to test:

```
myfun <- function(x, y, ...){
   in.tmp1 <- x
   in.tmp2 <- c(y, ...)
   out.tmp <- in.tmp1 + mean(in.tmp2)
   return(out.tmp)
}
```

Again, writing explicitly the column names the following approach works:

```
DT <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = seq(2, 20, 2), c = seq(5, 50, 5))
DT[, out := myfun(a,b,c), by = 1:nrow(DT)]
```

But I can't work out a more general solution for a large subset within the data.table specified by their columns names.

Comment: If you are doing `by = 1:nrow(DT)` you are doing it wrong. I would go with ```DT[, out := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = col]```

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. But does this work also with other functions (e.g. mean) or own written functions? I got the idea of `by = 1:nrow(DT)` by the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25431307/r-data-table-apply-function-to-rows-using-columns-as-arguments. For my first example, it does work as it is supposed to.

Comment: Well, like eddi said, it is better to vectorize. It depends on the function. The only case when you will use `by = 1:nrow(DT)` is when there is absolutely no other choice. Neither R or `data.table` were designed to work well by row, rather by columns/matrices. Again, it depends on your function. Also, if your data set is small, I guess it's not such a big deal to work by row.

Comment: I find this Q&A (and links therein) quite useful when considering row-wise operations: [How to do row wise operations on .SD columns in data.table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353036/how-to-do-row-wise-operations-on-sd-columns-in-data-table)

Comment: Thanks you all, but I still haven't managed to call a function with many parameters within the data.table. I think the problem are the quotes. I tried according to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603890/pass-column-name-in-data-table-using-variable-in-r to use `col <- quote(c(b,c))` and `DT[, out := myfun(a,eval(col)), by = 1:nrow(DT)]`. This theoretically works, but I still have the problem, that I have to type all e.g. 500 column names by hand. Suggestions anyone?!

Comment: @moe ultimate solution is to build desired `j` call using computing on the language, then just `DT[, eval(j)]`.

Comment: @jangorecki thanks for your comment. could you give me a more detailed example, plz?

Comment: @moe example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/37408321/2490497 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/34970993/2490497

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(a = 1:5, b = 5:1, c = 1, d = 2, e = 5:1)


myfun <- function(x, y, ...){
  in.tmp1 <- x
  in.tmp2 <- c(y, ...)
  out.tmp <- in.tmp1 + mean(in.tmp2)
  return(out.tmp)
}

my_vars <- c("a", "c", "d")

var_list <- mget(my_vars, envir = as.environment(dt))

names(var_list)[1:2] <- c("x", "y")

dt[, "out" := do.call(myfun, var_list)]
```

Here we collect an arbitrary set of columns in `my_vars` to `var_list`, a list of non-copied aliases for the appropriate columns from `dt`. It is possible to pass columns as arguments of a function in R using `do.call`, but the names of the elements in the argument list (here `var_list`) must match to the names of the arguments of the function (`myfun` has args "x" and "y" and "...", but the last takes elements of any name).

If you want to make more use of `data.table` and not use `mget`, try

```
## so myfun finds the correct columns for args "x" and "y"
setnames(dt, c("a", "c"), c("x", "y"))

my_vars <- c("x", "y", "d")
dt[, "out" := do.call(myfun, .SD), .SDcols = my_vars]
```

EDIT 2017-02-22: using unnamed columns also allowed in `do.call`.

```
dt[, "out" := do.call(myfun, unname(as.list(.SD))), .SDcols = my_vars]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your solution definitely works. However does it seem to me not as the intended approach using `data.table`. But I also might be wrong..

Comment: @moe I'm not certain what you mean by intended approach, but for more "data.table-like" code you can try the code block I added in my post. Since `do.call` tries to match columns to function arguments by the names of the columns, an alternative solution is to not have any names at all in the list passed on to `do.call`. This assumes the columns are in the correct order, however.